# New Outlook.Application generates runtime error '-2147319799(8002801d)' with Outlook Object Library

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code:

```vb
Sub SaveOutlookAtachments()

    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.Fs.Folders(1).Folders("my_folder")
    
    For Each i In fol.Items
        If i.Class = olMail Then
            Set mi = i
            Debug.Print mi.SenderName, mi.ReceivedTime, mi.Attachments.Count
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I get:

> runtime error '-2147319799(8002801d)'

and

> Automation Error: Library not registered

According to debugger the line that gives the issue is:

```
Set ol = New Outlook.Application
```

From what I researched, this might be a lack of reference made in the project (in this case for Outlook). The Outlook Object Library is checked:
[image]

Comment: I also have `microsoft scripting runtime` checked. Try that?

Comment: Which office version are you developing on - and which version does the users have?

Comment: What line of code throws the exception or gives the error message?

Comment: Unnecessary `.Fs` in `Set fol = ns.Fs.Folders(1).Folders("my_folder")`.

Comment: I have updated the question with line which gives the error message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not clear what line of code exactly gives the error message.

> runtime error '-2147319799(8002801d)' and Automation Error: Library not registered

The code and error message indicates that a COM reference required for the code base was not added. You need to set COM references on each machine if you migrate your VBA code to other machines.

Try to replace the following line of code:

```
Set ol = New Outlook.Application
```

With

```
Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

You may also may to try using the late-biding technology which doesn't required COM references added. Read more about that in the [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) article.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to go through my original error. However, it led me to `Run-time error '429': ActiveX component cant create object`. Currently figuring out how to get past this.